# Always present a view controller from portrait [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to always present a view controller from portrait?  For example, if I am in landscape mode with the home button to the left, and the view controller is presented from the left side.  It's always being presented from the bottom relative to the view

```
//When button is pressed
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewContoller") as! CustomViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

//App delegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

        UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    })
}
```